# Remove "Related Work Items" from Code Review Request (TFS)

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to remove "Related Work Items" from a Code Review Request that was mistakenly added?  (TFS2012, update2)

How about for another user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. Since the work item is related during the "pending changes" page. After the code review request created, there is no way to edit the related work item.

If you want to remove the wrong work item. So you may need to **abandon this code request** first. And in the "pending changes" page, right click the work item to remove work item. Create a code review request then.

[image]